# How do I share my notebooks in DataLab?

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

DataLab uses a shared service account but I can't see my team members' notebooks. How do we share notebooks between team members?

Answer (score 4):

Notebooks are stored in a git repository. If you click the "git Repository" icon on the notebook listing page it will take you to the Cloud Repo page in Google Cloud Dev Console. Pick the datalab_main branch in the dropdown and you will see files ready for commit. Once you commit, other users can click Refresh on the same page in Dev Console (Source | Browse in left nav bar) and they will see the changes and the new notebooks.

The other option is to download the notebook as an .ipynb file and share it that way.

Comment: This once-correct answer is no longer valid as the version has changed from beta1 to GA. See below for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above was for the beta1 version. For GA version released in March 2017, the mechanics have changed. Click the tree icon in the top bar to get to the git UI. Then you can perform normal git operations to push/pull as appropriate. 
Also see [this doc topic](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/docs/how-to/datalab-team) and related links.

Dinesh Kulkarni,

PM, Google Cloud Datalab

Comment: That ungit UI is really not fitting with the Google/Cloud branding and general UX - you're sending the user to a completely different style and look that makes it highly confusing and not intuitive.