# I have created charts with google-cloud-datalab. I now want to publish those to end users

Tags: google-cloud-datalab

I have created some great charts with google-cloud-datalab  My issue now is how can I make these visible/useable by end users.

Thanks

Comment: Please mark as answered if the answer below is clear enough, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the users are members of the same project, then you can share the notebook (see [How do I share my notebooks in DataLab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153852/how-do-i-share-my-notebooks-in-datalab)).

If you are using the %chart magic, you should be able to convert a notebook to HTML and share that. These charts are generated dynamically and require access to the underlying data to render, but the data will be included in the HTML file (however for tables you will get just the first page of data).

The other option is to use matplotlib or some other Python plotting library. You would need to export the data from BigQuery to (say) a Pandas dataframe and plot using that. You could then 
save the notebook as HTML or as an .ipynb file and share that. Many of these plotting libraries will generate the plot as a PNG image so that can be shared statically.